# Array Methods in javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I don't understand this method of `pop` and `unshift` in this array

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4];
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4];

let btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5");

btn5.onclick = function() {
  nums.unshift(nums.pop());

  for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    document.getElementById("btn" + ids[i]).innerHTML = nums[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: [Array#pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [Array#unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). What more specifically do you want to know about them?

Comment: pop() removes the last item in the array.  unshift() inserts an item at the beginning of the array.  So, this moves the last item to the start of the array.

Comment: It rotates the array by moving the last item to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`nums.unshift(nums.pop());` is:

```
// Remove the last entry from the array
const tmp = nums.pop();
// Insert it at the beginning of the array
nums.unshift(tmp);
```

So for instance, the first time that runs, `nums` starts with:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4]
```

so `pop` removes the `4` from the end, and inserts it at the beginning:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
```

Live Example:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4];

console.log("before:", JSON.stringify(nums));
nums.unshift(nums.pop());
console.log("after: ", JSON.stringify(nums));
```

Details on MDN: [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Answer (score 0):

Array [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes and return last element of an array. If you write something like,

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4];
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4];

const poppedValue = nums.pop(); //poppedValue = 4 and nums = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
```

And [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method push the item at the beginning of the array.

```
nums.unshift(poppedValue); // nums = [4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7];
```